# Retorno de Recursividade

Tags: php, laravel, recursão

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação onde eu coloco dados de origem, destino e custo em um array e o usuário deverá digitar a origem e o destino para que então o sistema vasculhe tal array e retorne o caminho com o menor custo.
Depois de várias tentativas, resolvi utilizar recursividade para trazer essa resposta. Vasculho através de um foreach os caminhos e todo caminho acessível que acaba dando no destino eu jogo em uma variável pra então armazenar em outro array para que finalmente eu possa fazer as comparações. segue código:

```
    public function calc($origem, $destino, $autonomia, $litro_combustivel) {

    $rotas = array (
        '0' => array (
            'ponto_inicial' => 'A',
            'ponto_final' => 'B',
            'distancia' => 10
        ),
        '1' => array (
            'ponto_inicial' => 'B',
            'ponto_final' => 'D',
            'distancia' => 15
        ),
        '2' => array (
            'ponto_inicial' => 'A',
            'ponto_final' => 'C',
            'distancia' => 20
        ),
        '3' => array (
            'ponto_inicial' => 'C',
            'ponto_final' => 'D',
            'distancia' => 30
        ),
        '4' => array (
            'ponto_inicial' => 'B',
            'ponto_final' => 'E',
            'distancia' => 50
        ),
        '5' => array (
            'ponto_inicial' => 'D',
            'ponto_final' => 'E',
            'distancia' => 30
        )
    );

    $melhores_rotas = array();
    $i = 1;
    $caminho = $origem;
    $primeira_origem = $origem;
    $origem = null; 
    $status = 0;
    $anterior = null;

  /*A B 10
    B D 15
    A C 20
    C D 30
    B E 50
    D E 30*/

    //FUNÇÃO RECURSIVA-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function calculaRota($rotas, $origem, $destino, $caminho, $melhores_rotas, $primeira_origem, $i, $status, $anterior) {

        if ($origem != $primeira_origem) {
            if ($status == 0) {
                $origem = $primeira_origem;
                $status = 1;
            }

            foreach ($rotas as $r) {

                if ($origem == $r['ponto_inicial']) {
                    $caminho = $caminho . $r['ponto_final'];
                    $anterior = $origem;
                    $origem = $r['ponto_final'];

                    if ($origem == $destino || $origem == "E") {

                        array_push($melhores_rotas, $caminho);
                        $caminho = substr($caminho, 0, -1);
                        $origem = $r['ponto_inicial'];

                    } else {
                        calculaRota($rotas, $origem, $destino, $caminho, $melhores_rotas, $primeira_origem, $i, $status, $anterior);

                        $origem = $r['ponto_inicial'];
                        $caminho = substr($caminho, 0, -1);
                    }

                }

            }

        } else {
            return $melhores_rotas;
        }


        if ($origem == $primeira_origem) {
            return $melhores_rotas;
        }


    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $dados = calculaRota($rotas, $origem, $destino, $caminho, $melhores_rotas, $primeira_origem, $i, $status, $anterior);

    dd($dados);


}
```

O Problema é... não recebo nada dentro da variável $dados e aparentemente pelo que eu pude perceber ele esta sobrepondo o conteúdo que eu vou adicionando dentro do array $melhores_rotas. Alguém tem algum de como eu posso fazer essas operações sem substituir o que tem no array?

Comment: Lucas o método `array_push()` que você já esta utilizando não sobrescreve o conteúdo do array de origem, ele adiciona as variáveis passada como parâmetros no final deste array, e não sobrescreve o mesmo.

Comment: Se sua ideia for apenas encontrar o caminho mais curto, no caso a melhor rota sugiro pesquisar sobre o algoritmo de dijkstra, ou Bellman Ford's, ou ate mesmo Floyd–Warshall's. Esses algoritmos irão buscar o menor caminho indo de um ponto A ao B